# Makefile experts needed

Tags: makefile

Can anyone who knows a thing or two about makefiles help me out with this one? I didn't write it, and there's a lot of stuff going on that I've never seen before.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Clear the implicit built in rules
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.SUFFIXES:
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ifeq ($(strip $(DEVKITARM)),)
$(error "Please set DEVKITARM in your environment. export DEVKITARM=<path to>devkitARM)
endif

include $(DEVKITARM)/gba_rules

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TARGET is the name of the output, if this ends with _mb a multiboot image is generated
# BUILD is the directory where object files & intermediate files will be placed
# SOURCES is a list of directories containing source code
# DATA is a list of directories containing data files
# INCLUDES is a list of directories containing header files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TARGET      :=  $(shell basename $(CURDIR))
BUILD       :=  build
SOURCES     :=  source
DATA        :=
GRAPHICS    :=  gfx 
INCLUDES    :=

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# options for code generation
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ARCH    :=  -mthumb -mthumb-interwork

CFLAGS  :=  -g -Wall -O3\
        -mcpu=arm7tdmi -mtune=arm7tdmi\
        -fomit-frame-pointer\
        -ffast-math \
        $(ARCH)

CFLAGS  +=  $(INCLUDE)

CXXFLAGS    :=  $(CFLAGS) -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions

ASFLAGS :=  $(ARCH)
LDFLAGS =   -g $(ARCH) -Wl,-Map,$(notdir $@).map

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# any extra libraries we wish to link with the project
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIBS    :=  -lgba

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# list of directories containing libraries, this must be the top level containing
# include and lib
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIBDIRS :=  $(LIBGBA)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# no real need to edit anything past this point unless you need to add additional
# rules for different file extensions
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ifneq ($(BUILD),$(notdir $(CURDIR)))
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export OUTPUT   :=  $(CURDIR)/$(TARGET)
export VPATH    :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(CURDIR)/$(dir)) \
            $(foreach dir,$(DATA),$(CURDIR)/$(dir))

export DEPSDIR  :=  $(CURDIR)/$(BUILD)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# automatically build a list of object files for our project
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CFILES      :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c)))
CPPFILES    :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp)))
SFILES      :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.s)))
BINFILES    :=  $(foreach dir,$(DATA),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.*)))
BMPFILES    :=  $(foreach dir,$(GRAPHICS),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.bmp)))

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# use CXX for linking C++ projects, CC for standard C
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ifeq ($(strip $(CPPFILES)),)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    export LD   :=  $(CC)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
else
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    export LD   :=  $(CXX)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
endif
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export OFILES   :=  $(addsuffix .o,$(BINFILES)) \
                    $(BMPFILES:.bmp=.o) \
                    $(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o) $(CFILES:.c=.o) $(SFILES:.s=.o)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# build a list of include paths
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
export INCLUDE  :=  $(foreach dir,$(INCLUDES),-I$(CURDIR)/$(dir)) \
            $(foreach dir,$(LIBDIRS),-I$(dir)/include) \
            -I$(CURDIR)/$(BUILD)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# build a list of library paths
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
export LIBPATHS :=  $(foreach dir,$(LIBDIRS),-L$(dir)/lib)

.PHONY: $(BUILD) clean

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$(BUILD):
    @[ -d $@ ] || mkdir -p $@
    @make --no-print-directory -C $(BUILD) -f $(CURDIR)/Makefile

all : $(BUILD)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
clean:
    @echo clean ...
    @rm -fr $(BUILD) $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).gba

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
else

DEPENDS :=  $(OFILES:.o=.d)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# main targets
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$(OUTPUT).gba   :   $(OUTPUT).elf

$(OUTPUT).elf   :   $(OFILES)


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The bin2o rule should be copied and modified
# for each extension used in the data directories
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This rule links in binary data with the .bin extension
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%.bin.o :   %.bin
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    @$(bin2o)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This rule links in binary data with the .raw extension
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%.raw.o :   %.raw
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    @$(bin2o)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This rule creates assembly source files using grit
# grit takes an image file and a .grit describing how the file is to be processed
# add additional rules like this for each image extension
# you use in the graphics folders 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%.s %.h : %.bmp %.grit
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    grit $< -fts -o$*

-include $(DEPENDS)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
endif
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My issue is with the make rules .bmp files. At the bottom, you can see the rule that should be called for all .bmp files in the /gfx directory (right now, there's just bg.bmp and bg.grit). Previously, I would get the error "no rule to make target bg.s needed by bg.o" even though, to me, that last rule clearly should apply to all .s files. After deleting the entire /build directory and trying again, I now get "no rule to make target bg.o needed by 2048.elf"

I can verify that running grit by hand (grit bg.bmp -fts -obg.s) generates both bg.s and bg.h files in the build folder.

Comment: I wish that you could come up with a better title.  This isn't a classifieds posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to add `GRAPHICS` directory to `VPATH`, the same way you've done for `SOURCES` and `DATA`. Otherwise make will have hard time figuring location of your bmp files and will not be able to figure out how to make corresponding object files.